# F# Seq<Seq<char>> convert to string

Tags: f#

Playing with F# and trying to get from string`abcdefghijklmnop` another string `aeimbfjncgkodhlp`.

```
let input ="abcdefghijklmnop"

let convertList (input:string)=
    input
    |> Seq.mapi(fun i ei->  i % 4, ei)
    |> Seq.groupBy (fst)
    |> Seq.map(fun (g,s)-> s |> Seq.map snd)

let result = convertList input

result
```

In my function final result is `seq<seq<char>>`, how to convert `seq<seq<char>>` to string?

Comment: `Seq.concat`, so just do `result |> Seq.concat`

Comment: You might want to join us at F# Slack. For trivial questions like this one, join the beginners channel.

Comment: @BentTranberg, you are right it helped me. Write answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In F#, the `string` type implements the `seq<_>` interface, which means that you can treat strings as sequences of characters, but getting the other way round is sadly a bit ugly.

One option is to turn `seq<seq<char>>` to just one `seq<char>` using `Seq.concat`, then convert it to `seq<string>` which is something you can then concatenate using `String.concat`:

```
result |> Seq.concat |> Seq.map string |> String.concat ""
```

Probably a more efficient, but less elegant option is to convert `seq<char>` to `array<char>` which you can then pass to `System.String` constructor:

```
result |> Seq.concat |> Seq.toArray |> System.String
```

Comment: The second answer is definitely a lot more efficient. You should do it the second way. The difference between creating N+1 new strings and creating 1 array and 1 string can be huge in terms of both performance and GC pressure, especially if this is done frequently, in a tight loop, or involving very large sequences. Of course, for just playing around it doesn't really matter, but sometimes efficiency is elegant!